# method __missing__ not working for dictionary in Conway's game of life

Tags: python, dictionary, conways-game-of-life

Apologies for my ignorance, I am completely new to micropython. As such my first foray is trying to implement code for Conway's game of life on a Raspberry Pi Pico using an 128x128 oled. I figured out how to do this using "brute force" (i.e., 128x128 matrices) but the optimized speed, even overclocking the Pi, is not what I would like (some ~2 sec between steps in the game). I ported to circuitpython, hoping to profit from ulab handling of matrices, but ended up with a slower end product (reasons not important, but I decided to go back to micropython).

I found online a separate approach using a dictionary of live cells that should accelerate matters greatly, as it only deals in each iteration strictly with those cells that need watching, neglecting the majority of cells that cannot evolve in a given step of the game. For this it relies on the use of the **missing** method to return zero values for any cell not presently in the dictionary. The (streamlined) code is below. It returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 62, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 46, in play_game
File "<stdin>", line 18, in check_cell
KeyError: (24, 13)
```

Which seems to indicate that **missing** is not working as it should (that Key indeed corresponds to the coordinates of a cell being accessed that is not present in the dictionary up front). I have tried a couple of things by importing defaultdict etc, to no avail. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
import time

class Life(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Life, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __missing__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return 0

    def check_cell(self, x: int, y: int): #determine if cell lives or dies
        x_coords = (x-1, x, x+1)
        y_coords = (y-1, y, y+1)
        total = 0

        for x_coord in x_coords:
            for y_coord in y_coords:
                total += self[x_coord, y_coord]

        live, dead = [], []
        cell = self[x, y]
        if total == 3 and not cell:
            live.append((x, y))
        elif total < 3 or total > 4 and cell:
            dead.append((x, y))
        elif cell:
            pass
        return live, dead

    def queue_cells(self):
        cells = []
        for x, y in self.keys():
            # Add all cell neighbors to the function.
            x_coords = (x-1, x, x+1)
            y_coords = (y-1, y, y+1)
            for x_coord in x_coords:
                for y_coord in y_coords:
                    cells.append((x_coord, y_coord))
#        print(cells)
        return cells

    def play_game(self):
        live, dead = [], []
        # Create all the transitions for the turn
        for x, y in self.queue_cells():
            step_live, step_dead = self.check_cell(x, y)
            live += step_live
            dead += step_dead
        # Apply all transitions. Remember that in Life, the state of the board
        # doesn't change until every cell is accounted for.
        for x, y in dead:
            if self[x, y]:
                del self[x, y]
        for x, y in live:
            self[x, y] = 1


game = Life({(25, 15): 1, (26, 15): 1, (25, 16): 1, (24, 16): 1, (25, 17): 1,})

while 1:
    game.play_game()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: As an aside, using inheritance seems misguided here. *Prefer composition over inheritance*

Comment: Anyway. I am not getting this error on CPython. This *may* be a sitaution where whatever Python implementation you are using doesn't support this feature (a real possibility for micropython). Anyway, that isn't necessary here. just use `my_dict.get(whatever, 0)`

Comment: Thanks for checking. Yes, I suspect this may be micropython-specific, but I find it odd that it does not complain on invoking the method, instead it just does not work. I will look into your suggestion, but I think that for the game to work using a dictionary one really needs __missing__ to work as advertised, as any possible cell position not in the dictionary could be probed during the game.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean "on invoking the method"? Are you calling it explicitly somewhere? It's just a hook, so I think from the POV of micropython it's just a random method that's never used.

Comment: You are right, the method seems to be entirely ignored. I am seeing some progress by using instead  def __getitem__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(args,0)  but for some reason that returns always "0", instead of only when the item is missing from the dictionary. I guess I just don't know enough python to figure this out. Very frustrating.

Comment: (apologies, I cannot even make the markdown formatting work to show code in the comments :-(

Comment: Problem solved! Tossed out def __missing__ and used     def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key,0)
instead. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I'm glad that works for you, but again, that isn't required, you could have just used `mydict.get(x, 0)` everywhere instead of `mydict[x]`, your algorithm does not (and will never) require you to use the `mydict[x]` *syntax*, it is essentially just a different calling convention